# TwitterText Framework run on simulator, not on device

Tags: swift, xcode, twitter, frameworks

I download the TwitterText framework from  [twitter-text library](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-text.html)

I ran the project, there is warning said that I have to change the project setting to the recommended setting, (I ignored it) then I built the project and got the TwitterText.framework , then I add it to my project library.

Now, the framework is working on the device but not working on simulator, but when I change setting on framework project setting to the recommended setting my App working on simulator but not working on the device!!!

I got this messages:
ld: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
missing required architecture arm64 in file...TwitterText
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried many solutions I read it in this site like changing (Build Active Architecture Only) in target Build settings to: No .. but nothing changes!!

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using Cocoa pods to install the framework , name:
" pod 'twitter-text', '~> 3.0' " and it's working in device and simulator.